# How to plot geohash with values on a map

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, folium, geohashing

| value | Geohash |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | w21zgk |
| 5 | w21z4q |
| ... | .... |

I would like to generate a choropleth map based on a table of geohashes with an associated value.

I tried to convert this to a geodataframe so that I could plot it out with folium. To do this, I needed a geometry column so I tried to convert the column of geohashes to polygons with `polygon_to_geohashes` from the [polygon-geohasher](https://github.com/Bonsanto/polygon-geohasher) library but this gives me a multipolygon object and I was unable to map it back to the respective values.

Does anyone have simple solution?